# Making an object available for Report

Tags: custom-object, custom-report-type

There is a case here when the object was created, the allow reports option was left unchecked, and I need that to be checked again so that I can allow reports checkbox to be enabled. However, when I check the list of custom object it doesn't shows up in the list, where other custom objects show up. It seems like when object was created the deployed option was also left unchecked. I have attached the snippet as well. Kindly let me know how I can enable reporting options again.
[image]

Comment: So how did you manage to do this screenshot?

Comment: I just took the snippet to show you guys that Enable reports option is unchecked. When I try to create a custom report type and then I see that the mentioned object is not having allow/enable reports option checked. Let me know how it can be checked again so that the object is available for reporting.